# Matplotlib legends not showing in plot method

Tags: python, matplotlib

After plotting line graph, I'm trying to add legends in the graph. But it does not show up. Below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ages_x = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
# Median Developer Salaries by Age
dev_y = [38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200,
         56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752]
# Median Python Developer Salaries by Age
py_dev_y = [45372, 48876, 53850, 57287, 63016,
            65998, 70003, 70000, 71496, 75370, 83640]
plt.plot(ages_x,dev_y,label = 'All Devs')
plt.plot(ages_x,py_dev_y,label = 'Python')
```

Comment: add `plt.legend()` at the end. Ref: [`legend_guide`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html), [`plt.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Comment: Thanks. This helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.legend()`
If you are unaware about it then follow the link.
[Plt.legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)